# How can I simulate the browser back button in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

We have a issue on our e-commerce site where users occasionally hit "checkout" twice and have their card charged twice.

It's a common enough bug and easy to fix, but I'd like to test the solution in our capybara setup. Once I've called click_button('checkout'), is it possible for me to pretend I'm a user hitting the browsers back button and then call click_button('checkout') a second time?

Answer (score 40):

You may want to try:

```
When(/^I go back$/) do
  page.evaluate_script('window.history.back()')
end
```

This will require running the senario in a javascript capable driver (selenium/celerity/akephalos)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `page.driver.go_back`, *if* you are using webkit as your capybara javascript driver via the `capybara-webkit` gem. Also requires `:js => true` for the `scenario`.

Comment: Works when using Selenium as the Capybara JavaScript driver as well.

Answer (score 8):

At least with `capybara` `2.10` and `selenium-webdriver` `2.53` this works:

```
When(/^I go back$/) do
  page.go_back
end
```

It's basically a shortcut for [jbarr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087801/881759) answer. For details more see the [capybara documentation on `go_back`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#go_forward-instance_method) .

BTW: The counter part is `page.go_forward`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this method in Webrat. I'm sure something similar for Capybara would work.

```
When(/^I go back$/) do
  visit request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
end
```

Side note: the "redirect_to :back" method didn't work for me for whatever reason.

Comment: except that will reload the previous page (unlike the browser back button), I'm hoping to just access the source again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This question and answer helped me a lot!

Just to add to @Jake Mallory's answer, selenium is now part of capybara and you can fairly easily run javascript in the test by adding  `:js => true`  (and possibly a couple more tweaks) as described in these two tutorials:

http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/
http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast